# Detect rootcontroller in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.5

I have using two types of controller in my application i.e. **NavigationController** and **presentViewController**.
How can I detect base controller at any instance through code i.e I am using navigation or **presentviewcontroller** to transist one **viewcontroller** to another **viewcontroller**?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for take rootviewcontroller of navigation:

```
UIViewController *topViewController = [self.navigationController topViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

for present modal view controller check out the 'presentingViewController' property of UIViewController and for navigation you can get the array of view controllers `NSArray *ArryViewControllers=[self.navigationController viewControllers];` and then get the object at index 0 . this will be the root view controller of that navigation controller.